# Django: “limit_choices_to” doesn't work on ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-forms, many-to-many

I have 3 models, 2 of them belongs via ManyToManyField

```
class Vkgroupstomonitor(models.Model):
    vk_groups = (('https://vk.com/southitpark','https://vk.com/southitpark'), ('https://vk.com/graphgrail', 'https://vk.com/graphgrail'))
    vk_group_name= models.CharField(max_length=255, default='0')#, choices=vk_groups, default='0')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.vk_group_name    

class Sourcetomonitor(models.Model):
    source_names = (('Вконтакте', 'Вконтакте'), ('Facebook', 'Facebook'), ('Twitter (скоро)', 'Twitter (скоро)'))
    source_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=source_names, default='0')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.source_name  

class Userproject(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="project", verbose_name=_("Владелец проекта"))

    vk_groups = models.ManyToManyField(Vkgroupstomonitor, null=True, blank=True, related_name="vkgroups", verbose_name=_("Группы Вконтакте"))
    source_name = models.ManyToManyField(Sourcetomonitor, null=True, blank=True, related_name="sourcename", verbose_name=_("Название источника"))

    name = models.CharField(u'Название проекта', unique=True, max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('userproject_edit', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

In forms.py i have modelform:

```
class UserprojectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Userproject
        fields = ['name', 'user', 'description', 'vk_groups', 'source_name', 'date_updated', 'date_until'] #'date_created',  cannot add django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (date_created) specified for Userproject

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserprojectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['vk_groups'].queryset = Userproject.objects.filter(vk_groups=self.instance.vk_groups)
```

So how to change this line 
**self.fields['vk_groups'].queryset = Userproject.objects.filter(vk_groups=self.instance.vk_groups)**  to get Vkgroupstomonitor instances in multiselect field that limited to current Userproject only ?

tried Userproject.objects.filter(vk_groups=self.instance.vk_vk_group_name) and Userproject.objects.filter(vk_group_name=self.instance.vk_groups) but another error: "Cannot resolve keyword 'vk_group_name' into field. Choices are: date_created, date_until, date_updated, description, id, name, source_name, user, user_id, vk_groups"

Now it show all options, i want this to work in admin and frontend in create and update views.

Comment: `self.instance.vk_groups` is not a query set, but a related manager. Have you tried `self.fields['vk_groups'].queryset = self.instance.vk_groups.all()` instead?

Comment: @schwobaseggl this works, but another problem: now when i add value from popup it added to database, but when i save form it shows error "Select a valid choice. %(value)s is not one of the available choices.". where %value is pk as i guess